# how to change a node value in python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<info>
  </tags>
  </tags>
  <area>
<media>
    <options>
         <name>Jaipur</name>
    </options>
</media>
  </area>
</info>
```

i am totaly new in python, here is my xml file and i want to edit element value at run time in python
it means I want to change the **`<name>Jaipur</name>` to `<name>Mumbai</name>`**

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/easiest-way-to-parse-xml-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the example is not valid xml. You can use `xml.etree` that comes included:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
xmlstr="""\
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<area>
  <media>
    <options>
         <name>Jaipur</name>
    </options>
 </media>
</area>"""
doc=et.fromstring(xmlstr)
doc.find('.//name').text='Mumbai'
print et.tostring(doc)
```

output:

```
<area>
  <media>
    <options>
         <name>Mumbai</name>
    </options>
 </media>
</area>
```